# display a select list depending on other select

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to show a second select depending on what i choose on the first select !! here is wjat i proceed

```
$("select#semestre").change(function(){
   var sem = $(this).val();
  var data  = {"sem":sem};
  $.post('myScript.php',data,function(result){
     $("select#matiere").append(result);
  });
});
```

my code work fine at all but when i change a select option it add another options to the old one , what i want is to remove the old one and display another result

Comment: Try changing `$("select#matiere").append(result);` to `$("select#matiere").html(result);`. `.append()`, as the name suggests, will append the code to the element, where `.html()` will replace the current HTML inside the element with the new HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you choose another select option you clean the select and append to it the result which coming by the request !! not sure but i'm suggestion you to try this

```
$("select#semestre").change(function(){
   var sem = $(this).val();
  var data  = {"sem":sem};
  $.post('myScript.php',data,function(result){
     //here the select will be empty and then it will be fulled with the result coming from your post
     $("select#matiere").html("");
     $("select#matiere").append(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('select#...').empty()` vs `.html("")` would probably be a cleaner solution.  https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: @ArcSine it worked fine with both of them thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

`.append()` will... you guessed, append to the element!
Use `.html()` instead, i.e.:

```
$("select#matiere").html(result);
```